# i cant send json to asp mvc using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

im  trying to send json parameter to asp request handler like this:

```
  $scope.SaveCarUpgrades = function () {
                var parameter = JSON.stringify(resultCarUpgrades);



                $http.get("/ProfileEditor/saveUserCarUpgrades/" + $scope.useridCarUpgrades,
                    { params: { name: parameter }}
                ).then(onsuccess, onfail);
                function onsuccess(response) {
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        $scope.saveUpgradesResult = "save upgrades success";
                    } else {
                        $scope.saveUpgradesResult = "save upgrades failed" + response.status;
                    }
                }

                function onfail(response) {
                    $scope.saveUpgradesResult = "save upgrades failed" + response.status;
                  //  $scope.saveUpgradesResult = parameter;
                }
            }
```

c# request handler is something very simpe. its just for testing  right now:

```
   public string SaveUserCarUpgrades(string id)
        {
            string result = id;
            var data = Request.QueryString["name"];
            return id;
        }
```

the problem is i always get 404 if if use json as parameter. (its a complex long json) but as simple json or simple string the response is fine. i dont think the problem is mime type as i set it in iis express in devcmd.

thank you for helping

Comment: Why are you using `Request.QueryString`? In MVC the parameter should be part of the input parameters to the function, e.g. `SaveUserCarUpgrades(string id, string name)` perhaps

Comment: @ADyson i also tested sending json as parameter but i only get 400 status response instead of 404

Comment: Can you show exactly what you did?

Comment: @ADyson code above is all id did for different type of requsts. it works on plain text but not in json format

Comment: You said you changed it somehow to test it as a parameter, and got a different response. That's what I wanted you to show